# Magento 2.4 Database Connection Usage

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I am using Magento 2.4 on AWS and I have been noticing that there are many MySQL connections in sleep, is this normal? Should I be looking into this to fix it, if yes then where can I look to fix this?

This website is running one store with around 80+ products and these processes are in there when there's no user on the website too!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever's been having this problem, its because of stuck consumer runner cron jobs waiting for max messages to be reached. Please see the following article, this fixed my problem:

https://www.cadence-labs.com/2020/03/magento-2-stuck-or-long-running-cron-after-upgrade-to-2-3-x/

I'm using Magento 2.4.0 and by default it was waiting to reach max messages limit, so I changed the parameter `consumers_wait_for_messages` in `env.php` to `0` as mentioned in the blog and now the cron job does not wait for max messages to be reached and closes the database connection.

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
],
```

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-envphp.html#consumers_wait_for_messages