# MySql Sleep Connections

Tags: database, mysql8, mysql-sleep-connection, high-cpu-usage

We are facing huge MYSQL CPU usage. While investigating we found that there are MySQL sleep connections during the CRON run. Is there any way to reduce the CPU usage and the sleep connections. Please check the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

We found the following suggestions:

[Magento 2.4 Database Connection Usage](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340413/magento-2-4-database-connection-usage)

We have a large catalog and large number of tier prices, approx. 2000000. Is this suggestion suitable to fix our problem. Please suggest a better solution if you have any.

Thanks.

| Id      | User                       | Host            | db                     | Command | Time | State        |Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | Progress |
+---------+----------------------------+-----------------+
| 2777768 | user_user_live_245 | 127.0.0 | user_user_live | Sleep   | 2704 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |    0.000 |
| 2777774 | user_user_live_245 | 127.0.0.1:3 | user_user_live | Query   |    0 | Sending data | UPDATE `catalog_product_index_price_temp` AS `i`
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cpiw` ON cpiw.website_id = i.website_id
INNER JOIN `catalogrule_product_price` AS `cpp` ON cpp.product_id = i.entity_id AND cpp.customer_group_id = i.customer_group_id AND cpp.website_id = i.website_id AND cpp.rule_date = cpiw.website_date
SET `i`.`final_price` = LEAST(final_price, IFNULL(cpp.rule_price, i.final_price)), `i`.`min_price` = LEAST(min_price, IFNULL(cpp.rule_price, i.min_price))
WHERE (i.entity_id IN (13, 14, 18, 383, 387, 395, 399, 410, 414, 416, 418, 419, 423, 424, 429, 431, 433, 436, 437, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 459, 461, 463, 472, 473, 474, 475, 481, 482, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 494, 509, 510, 511, 513, 516, 518, 558, 559, 560, 561, 565, 566, 568, 582, 584, 585, 587, 588, 589, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630)) |    0.000 |
| 2782841 | user_user_live_245 | localhost       | user_user_live | Query   |    0 | starting     | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 2782875 | user_user_live_245 | 127.0.0.1:64063 | user_user_live | Sleep   |    0 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |    0.000 |

Comment: Please post TEXT results of this query - SELECT 'SLEEPING time use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time)  
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";

Comment: SLEEPING time use | COUNT(*)
 | SUM(time)
 |
+-------------------+----------+-----------+
| SLEEPING time use |        3 |     12116 |

Comment: Since there are only 3 averaging more than one hour each, could you post TEXT results of SELECT * from information_schema.processlist WHERE command="Sleep" \G;

Comment: COMMAND | TIME | STATE | INFO | TIME_MS    | STAGE | MAX_STAGE | PROGRESS | MEMORY_USED | MAX_MEMORY_USED | EXAMINED_ROWS | QUERY_ID   | INFO_BINARY | TID   |
 Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL |     22.296 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       81496 |         6436936 |             0 | 1607888880 | NULL        | 46285 |
 Sleep   |  157 |       | NULL | 157966.443 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       81496 |           81496 |             0 | 1607823893 | NULL        | 46735 |

Comment: Could you login as root and post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; ?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the full response to the command.

Comment: The UPDATE in the list appears to be not harmful if you run it again.  If you agree, would you Post TEXT results of EXPLAIN UPDATE ...... to see how many rows are being examined to get the UPDATE accomplished ?  The Sending Data phase can be improved with my.cnf [mysqld] section request of net_buffer_length=98304  to reduce packet count sent/received.  This value is 16384 today. Please view my profile and make contact.